# read a tar file in c so as to get file specifications and other attributes

Tags: c

I was trying to write a program that can read a tar file, list each filename, file size, and other attributes.I started out by just printing all the contents.But this does not work.It prints some weird things like -

?Δ???y???*?rg?=M?\????ZG?0??ϚF٫ӕŉDM??N?G?b???}?s?C|S?n??!?-=??h7h%n|???l?E?M?>??d???h???KY?Ly?n?!}SYv?/???4?;????*0?\?l3????wEʗÍ(?h?.5"?K#??Uew?????+??ܻuGt????c?s?'??l????ߙ?J?????'???.???ڼ.?W+??h????H
?{Ž?e?h??M?[?-?0??F??vc??X??Ns??l?^??]m?$n?\??e?!?ԕ?;gdܻ???'??/~?ބ?????R??;?*?Le5%:?M^?w??7"?yI??a?4????D??$ɵq??4???7?"?toUyI??V??ǯ??$s????g/`???\Z?n?k`?,M?t??@h9!?{y??g?1?A?a]??̷???S?j?w?n?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

        int main()
        {
           char buf[1000];
           FILE *fp;
           char file_name[25];
           printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
           gets(file_name);
           fp = fopen(file_name,"r"); // read mode

           if( fp == NULL )
           {
              perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);
           while (fgets(buf,1000, fp)!=NULL)
          {     
              printf("%s",buf);
                                }
                fclose(fp);
                return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A tar file is encoded in a binary format. You will either need to use `popen` to open a pipe to tar (e.g. to `tar tvf` to list contents), or use a C library for processing tar files. Two such libraries are `libtar` and `libarchive`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard that describes the layout of a 'tar' file:
http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html

Basically, you need to read the header of the file. The header structure is defined in `src/tar.h` in the GNU tar source package:

```
/* tar Header Block, from POSIX 1003.1-1990.  */

/* POSIX header.  */

struct posix_header
{                              /* byte offset */
  char name[100];               /*   0 */
  char mode[8];                 /* 100 */
  char uid[8];                  /* 108 */
  char gid[8];                  /* 116 */
  char size[12];                /* 124 */
  char mtime[12];               /* 136 */
  char chksum[8];               /* 148 */
  char typeflag;                /* 156 */
  char linkname[100];           /* 157 */
  char magic[6];                /* 257 */
  char version[2];              /* 263 */
  char uname[32];               /* 265 */
  char gname[32];               /* 297 */
  char devmajor[8];             /* 329 */
  char devminor[8];             /* 337 */
  char prefix[155];             /* 345 */
                                 /* 500 */
};
```

Comment: I tried reading first 500 bytes to get the first file entry but gives me the same result as the question